# Ubuntu package for gnome system admin guide?

Tags: gnome, package-management, documentation

Is there a documentation package available for Gnome System Administrator's guide?

http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/

I wish to have a offline copy preferably as a ubuntu package. The website does not provide any links for download.

Comment: How about [Ubuntu Server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download is [here](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/system-admin-guide-html-2.32.0.tar.gz) on the same site. That will get you a gzipped tar of the entire html page.

Alternatively, load the [entire html page](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/2.32/system-admin-guide.html) in your browser and save it. If you want to save it as PDF, simply select the tab the page is open in, go to your browser's menu and click *print* > *print to file* and choose pdf as the filetype and a location to save it in. If this is unsuccessful install `cups-pdf`, restart your browser, load the gnome page in link 2, and open the browser menu, click *print* > *PDF* and choose your options. (By default cups-pdf will create a folder called pdf in your home folder.

Comment: I wish I could have a ubuntu package, which updates automatically.